# Including "Too Localized" in the what not to ask

Tags: feature-request, faq-for-site

As of right now, [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18152/looking-for-a-royalty-free-sci-fi-sounding-song-thats-100-long-and-costs-5) is worded is such a way it is too localized (I submitted an edit to try to be more general without changing the meaning, so it might be changed now).

I was looking in the FAQ, under "What kind of questions should I not ask here?", it doesn't say anything about questions are are too localized, but that is a reason we can flag a question. Can that criteria be added to the list?

Comment: Note that the FAQ does mention that "too localized" is a possible close reason under the ["why some questions are closed"](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq#close) section.

Answer (score 3):

As Josh pointed out, it is in the close section of the FAQ:

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq#close

additionally, this is also noted in the "How to Ask" advice, which is linked a number of places including the FAQ and the question ask page itself:

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask

> #### Make it relevant to others
>
> We like to help as many people at a time as we can. Make it clear how your question is relevant to more people than just you, and more of us will be interested in your question and willing to look into it.